# Dual boot Windows 10 from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04

I want to know how to Dual boot windows 10 from Ubuntu 16.04 but I don't know how. I have a windows 10 flash drive to download it from.

Comment: You shouldve  installed Ubuntu after Windows, because it tends to overwrite the grub bootloader.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Answer (score 1):

(This method does not work for computers with UEFI boot. In consequence, it won't work for pre-installed Windows 8 and some pre-installed with Windows 7.)

IF SOMETHING GOES WRONG?

[Reinstall Grub Tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2)

Create a NTFS partition for Windows using Gparted

(`sudo apt install gparted`)

**MAKE SURE TO BACKUP THE MBR!**

Install Windows normally

Then boot into a LIVECD (try ubuntu without installing)

We need the handy-dandy Gparted again.

Mount the root partition inside the LiveCD.

Then, restore the MBR.

Now setup the grub to boot windows. :)

Comment: If this has helped you, please click the tick to mark this as *answered!*

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu recommends you install Windows first.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: It is possible  however to do a ubuntu and windows dual-boot.